# What is the best approach for using CiviCRM as an app on mobile?

Tags: extension, mobile

What extension is by now the most succesful in displaying CiviCRM content in a mobile app?

(If you have any personal experiences, please tell about them...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combination of the two extensions [CiviMobile](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobile) (thanks @rahulbile) and [Summary fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields/) is very interesting.

The CiviMobile extension is poorly documented, but after a while I figured out that it uses profiles to choose which fields to display. Also different profiles for each contact type: Individual, Household and Organizations. It took me more time before I figured out that it used the restricted profile_ids 4, 5 and 6, which can be edited to add more fields.

Then I could also use some of the fields from Summary fields, to display relevant contribution informations as search result on the contact.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that apps are as common as using responsive design for the site and then creating special pages that don't put too much onto page.

Answer (score 0):

We have found the [Extension CiviMobile](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobile) quite good. Have you checked it ?

Comment: Tried it before, and tried it again now. Do you know how to modify it to be able to show phone numbers as well as email adresses?

Comment: A [good StackExchange answer](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) offers more than a link— in fact, an answer consisting only of a link is grounds for deletion. What do you like about this extension? What others have you tried? Who are your users?