# Which mobile Apps or Extension work well for what scenario

Tags: mobile

(EDIT - I changed this from a question asking for an App for the 'general contact/member to a more generic one that hopefully gives good enough across the whole range of scenarios)

There are several questions about Apps that i have found eg
- [CiviCRM on mobile phone](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17838/civicrm-on-mobile-phone)
- [What is the best approach for using CiviCRM as an app on mobile?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-is-the-best-approach-for-using-civicrm-as-an-app-on-mobile)
- [CiviCRM on mobile phone](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17838/civicrm-on-mobile-phone)

My sense at this early point of discovery is that most effort has been going in to Apps for the admin/organiser, rather than just for a general user/member who may want to 
- view and update their profile and membership.
- see their relationships and click through to those relationships eg employer, region and club.
- search for and register for events through the app

Hence this question will hopefully flesh out what features each offers and what particular scenarios they may be best applied to.

Comment: I'd like to add one more, we also have mobile apps for supporters, including members, fundraisers or general contacts interested in staying in touch. More to come (we're revamping our site at present)

Comment: Great - keen to build up the list, and flesh out with what special powers each has. Can you add a link to the repo?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an initial list - hoping we can collectively flesh this out so it is a useful reference document

[CiviContact](https://agileware.com.au/civicontact/) - AgileWare

- Android and IOS

[CiviMobile](https://civimobile.org/) - AgiliWay

- Android and IOS

[SmartCivi](https://github.com/artechconsultancyltd/uk.co.artechconsultancy.module.smartcivi) - ArtTech

- Android only

[CiviMobile Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobile) - WebAccess

NOTE: I will do my best to update this list with more info/summaries if folk post Comments or separate Answers

Comment: I'm on a similar quest for a way to help not tech savvy users have a better experience let's say with Contacts and Cases. So far all apps I found are the ones listed above. Civimobile is working well to help our charity institution to manage events, food distribution, attendance, etc. Now I'm looking for ways to create Cases/activities from a mobile device. The web interface is not the most easy to use for a normal user. I'm trying CiviContact but can't make it work (yet) by following the instructions in the readme.  I'll keep checking here in case other ideas pop up.